# conversation scope for spring

Tags: spring, jsf, serialization, conversation-scope, orchestra

We have java web app that runs on spring and jsf 1.2. 
Also we use apache orchestra as framework for Conversation scope. 
But we are always having problems with the orchestra and the last problem was that orchestra ConversationManager does not support serialization, so we can not serialize session and replicate it to different server instance. But we need session replication. So we decided to get rid of orchestra and use some alernative for conversation scope. Actually we use conversations mostly to extend request scope, so switching to view scope could solve our problem.

- Maybe someone knows which libraries we can use to get conversation or view scope as spring custom scope?
- Switching to seam is not an option, too much code coupled with spring. Can switching to jsf 2 solve our problem?
- Or maybe somebody serialized session with orchestra conversations inside?
- Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://www.jroller.com/RickHigh/entry/adding_a_jsf_view_scope

Comment: It seem to be very easy. Is anybody using something like that?